# How to move to changed lines in Emacs using vc-diff?

Tags: svn, emacs

In using vc-diff (I am using Subversion), is there any keystroke in emacs where we can move only to the changed lines quickly? It's quite unconvenience if we move to those lines using arrow key.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's `diff-hunk-next` (by default mapped to <kbd>M-TAB</kbd>) and a corresponding `diff-hunk-prev`.  Looking at the mode documentation and keymap with <kbd>C-h m</kbd> is generally a good way to figure this kind of thing out; the commands are usually pretty logically named.

You might also investigate using `ediff-revision` instead of `vc-diff` (just hit <kbd>RET</kbd> three times to get it to default to comparing the same stuff as `vc-diff` would).  I've got it mapped to <kbd>C-x v e</kbd>.

Comment: ah, I am about to ask, what is the key to display keybinding for the active mode. You've pre answered it for me, <kbd>C-h m</kbd>. I use it Windows Environment, and the default keybinding is <kbd>TAB</kbd>

I'll try with ediff-revision. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `?` inside the diff window to get info for commands short keys and their usage.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the most important part of the <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> documentation on the key bindings is this note:

> When the buffer is read-only, the ESC prefix is not necessary.

Which description slightly obfuscates the fact that it is referring to keys using the Meta modifier.

Hence all of the following (by default in Emacs 26.1) can be used when the buffer is read-only (as it typically is when viewing a diff):

```
n             diff-hunk-next
p             diff-hunk-prev

TAB           diff-hunk-next
<backtab>     diff-hunk-prev

SPC           scroll-up-command
S-SPC         scroll-down-command
DEL           scroll-down-command

<             beginning-of-buffer
>             end-of-buffer

N             diff-file-next
P             diff-file-prev

}             diff-file-next
{             diff-file-prev

RET           diff-goto-source
o             diff-goto-source
<mouse-2>     diff-goto-source

k             diff-hunk-kill
K             diff-file-kill

0 .. 9        digit-argument
-             negative-argument

?             describe-mode
h             describe-mode
```